# can I use async.waterfall inside async.parallel?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, parallel-processing, waterfall

I want to call two functions and get the results in parallel but one of the function's results needed to be adapted. So the function structure is:

```
function test(cb) {
async.parallel({
    func1: function foo(cb1) {
        cb(null, {});
    },
    func2: function bar(cb2) {
        async.waterfall([
            function adapt1(next) {
                //do something;
            },
            function adapt2(next) {
                //do something;
            }
        ], function handler(err, res) {
            //do something.
        })
    }
}, function handler2(err, res) {
    cb(null, {});
})
```

}

However, it just seems hang there forever. not sure if I can use async in this way....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can! You have to be sure to call your callbacks in the correct order and in the first place. For example, func1 should be calling `cb1` not `cb`. Secondly, your waterfall is not invoking their callbacks at all.
Take this code for example.

```
'use strict';

let async = require('async');

function test(callback) {
  async.parallel({
    func1: function(cb) {
      cb(null, { foo: 'bar' });
    },
    func2: function(cb) {
      async.waterfall([
        function(cb2) {
          cb2(null, 'a');
        },
        function(prev, cb2) {
          cb2(null, 'b');
        }
      ], function(err, result) {
        cb(err, result);
      });
    }
  }, function(err, results) {
    callback(err, results);
  });
}

test(function(err, result) {
  console.log('callback:', err, result);
});
```

Outputs: `callback: null { func1: { foo: 'bar' }, func2: 'b' }`